# Content-Type is not added to axios post request headers

Tags: javascript, post, axios, content-type

I am working with axios and trying to send a post request in the below format in javascript

```
let api_post_request = async (resourcePath, params, file, options) => {
let headers = {
        ...(getAccessToken()),
        'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
    };
    try{
        await axios({
            method: 'post',
            headers: headers,
            baseURL: `${Constants.PATH.BASE_URL}`,
            url: `${resourcePath}`,
            ...(params ? { params: params } : ""),
            ...(file ? {data : {file : file}} : "")
        });
    }
```

Bearer token is set in the Authorization key, however, Content-Type is not found in the request headers of network tab. Am I using the right request format. And due to this am getting **Request failed with status code 415** error.

Comment: read [this](https://axios-http.com/docs/multipart) - I've always found axios docs unreadable, so stopped using it, but the implication of that page is that post data is a separate argument

Answer (score 0):

Try this example of axios documentation  https://axios-http.com/docs/multipart

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const form = new FormData();
form.append('my_field', 'my value');
form.append('my_buffer', new Blob(['some content']));

axios.post('https://example.com', form)
```